# Some div(s) not displaying when using createElement and appendChild

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create 4 div(s) that are supposed to have a width of 5px and sit at the top, bottom, left and right margins of the viewport, essentially acting all together as a frame or border to the page.

Here is my code:

```
function border () {

edgeT = document.createElement('div');
edgeT.style.position = "fixed"
edgeT.style.left = 0;
edgeT.style.top = 0;
edgeT.style.right = 0;
edgeT.style.width = "5px";
edgeT.style.backgroundColor= "black";
document.body.appendChild(edgeT);

edgeB = document.createElement('div');
edgeB.style.position = "fixed"
edgeB.style.left = 0;
edgeB.style.right = 0;
edgeB.style.bottom = 0;
edgeB.style.width = "5px";
edgeB.style.backgroundColor= "black";
document.body.appendChild(edgeB);

edgeL = document.createElement('div');
edgeL.style.position = "fixed"
edgeL.style.left = 0;
edgeL.style.top = 0;
edgeL.style.bottom = 0;
edgeL.style.width = "5px";
edgeL.style.backgroundColor= "black";
document.body.appendChild(edgeL);

edgeR = document.createElement('div');
edgeR.style.position = "fixed"
edgeR.style.top = 0;
edgeR.style.bottom = 0;
edgeR.style.right = 0;
edgeR.style.width = "5px";
edgeR.style.backgroundColor= "black";
document.body.appendChild(edgeR);

}
```

For some reason, when calling the function, the left and right divs (i.e. edgeL and edgeR) are displayed properly, but there is no trace of edgeT and edgeB (top and bottom ones). I cannot understand why since the code is exactly the same for all four of them. FYI the problem is relevant in both Chrome and Firefox.

I know I could use CSS to achieve the same result, but since this is mostly a learning exercise I would still like to understand what is causing the issue in this case.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define for the top and bottom divs `width: 100%` and `height: 5px` (they're aligned horizontally) and for the left and right divs `width: 5px` and `height: 100%` (aligned vertically).

```
var edgeT = document.createElement('div');
edgeT.style.position = "fixed"
edgeT.style.top = 0;
edgeT.style.left = 0;
edgeT.style.width = "100%";
edgeT.style.height = "5px";
edgeT.style.backgroundColor= "black";
document.body.appendChild(edgeT);

var edgeB = document.createElement('div');
edgeB.style.position = "fixed"
edgeB.style.bottom = 0;
edgeB.style.left = 0;
edgeB.style.width = "100%";
edgeB.style.height = "5px";
edgeB.style.backgroundColor= "black";
document.body.appendChild(edgeB);

var edgeL = document.createElement('div');
edgeL.style.position = "fixed"
edgeL.style.left = 0;
edgeL.style.top = 0;
edgeL.style.width = "5px";
edgeL.style.height = "100%";
edgeL.style.backgroundColor= "black";
document.body.appendChild(edgeL);

var edgeR = document.createElement('div');
edgeR.style.position = "fixed"
edgeR.style.right = 0;
edgeR.style.top = 0;
edgeR.style.width = "5px";
edgeR.style.height = "100%";
edgeR.style.backgroundColor= "black";
document.body.appendChild(edgeR);
```

Comment: Thank you! Spent half an hour on it and completely overlooked that I was setting the width rather than the height for top and bottom... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the top and the bottom then you need to give them a **height**, not a width.